# Function to iterate trough comma separated hex strings and decode them in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hex, decode

I need a little help with a function in dart/flutter I am trying to write.

There are bunch of HEX encoded strings separated by comma and joined together in one `String`.

For example:
`String input = 'HexEncodedStr1,HexEncodedStr2,HexEncodedStr3'`

I need to decode each of those strings and output them in the same comma separated form:

`String output = 'HexDecodedStr1,HexDecodedStr2,HexDecodedStr3'`

Currently, I am using `hex.dart` package as string decoder but I am struggling to separate each encoded string before decoding it with `hex.dart`:

```
import 'package:hex/hex.dart';

//The decode function
String decode(hexString) {
  if (hexString != "") {
     hexString = HEX.decode(hexString);
     return hexString;
  } else {
     return "N/A";
  }
}

void main() {

  String test = decode('776f726c64,706c616e65740d0a');
  print(test); //world,planet

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about splitting the string and joining decoded parts afterwards?

```dart
void main() {
  final decoded = '776f726c64,706c616e65740d0a'
      .split(',')
      .map(decode)
      .join(',');
  print(decoded); //world,planet
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use string.split(",");

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html

```
String input = 'HexEncodedStr1,HexEncodedStr2,HexEncodedStr3'
var inputSplit = input.split(",");
```

Now you have a list of substring. I think that you can then you a for loop or foreach.

```
inputSplit.forEach((element) => print(decode(element);));
```

or:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < inputSplit.length; i++)
 {
    var oneHex = decode(inputSplit[i]);
    print(oneHex);
 }
```